# Javascript: null or undefined or not a function

Tags: javascript, html, null, onclick, undefined

I'm using the following code to toggle the visibility of some divs. The script is placed at the top of a section of html code that acts as a home page feed for a site.

```
var divs = ["div1", "div2", "div3", "div4", "div5", "div6", "div7"];
var visibleDivId = null;

function toggleVisibility(divId) {
    "use strict";

    if (visibleDivId === divId) {
        visibleDivId = null;

    } else {
        visibleDivId = divId;
    }
    hideNonVisibleDivs();
}

function hideNonVisibleDivs() {
    "use strict";
    var i, divId, div;

    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        divId = divs[i];
        div = document.getElementById(divId);

        if (visibleDivId === divId) {
            div.style.display = "block";

        } else {
            div.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

The toggleVisibility function is called by an onclick event in the html. The js console is telling me that toggleVisibility is null or undefined or is not a function. Why would it do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't think this is possible to answer without the HTML - presumably `toggleVisibility` is not present in the global scope when the onlick handler is called.

Comment: Sounds like scoping because you have "use strict" but you aren't var-ing the functions (i.e. `var toggleVisibility = function () { ///do stuff}`).

Comment: You're also missing a "closed" curly bracket at the end of function hideNonVisibleDivs() .

Comment: @KhalilRavanna—replacing function declarations with function expressions will do nothing useful. Declarations are processed before expressions, so declarations will be available to be called before expressions are.

Comment: Are you including the script in which the above JavaScript is located after the element with the click handler is defined?

Comment: I put that code through three different verifiers and none of them found the missing bracket. I should have just trusted my own eyes.